# What is the easiest way to make tuples of the rows in an array?

Tags: python, numpy

Say I have an `X by 2` np.ndarray.

```
1 2
3 4
3 6
```

What is the easiest way to make tuples out of the rows

```
  (1 ,2)
  (3, 4)
  (3, 6)
```

other than

```
L = [ tuple(A[i,:]) for i in range(X)]

L = array(L)
```

Is there a built in function to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since numpy arrays iterate by rows, just using a plain old list comprehension is ok:

```
>>> a = np.arange(1, 7).reshape((3,2))
>>> a
array([[1, 2],
       [3, 4],
       [5, 6]])
>>> [tuple(row) for row in a]
[(1, 2), (3, 4), (5, 6)]
```

You could also `map` it:

```
>>> map(tuple, a)
[(1, 2), (3, 4), (5, 6)]
```

Comment: Cool, the `map` is probably my best bet.  Thanks